# Connection between quotient maps and embeddings

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Currently reading about topology and it seems that there is some connections between quotient maps and embeddings. Working on following problem now

> Assume that $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ are both continuous maps and that the composition $g \circ f$ is the identity. Show that $g$ is a quotient map and that $f$ is an embedding.

What I've been able to show is that since the identity is bijective we have that $g$ must be surjective. Now $g$ defines a quotient map if the equivalence $$U \subset X \iff g^{-1}(U) \subset Y$$ holds ($U$ and $g^{-1}(U)$ are open sets). By assumption $g$ was continuous so $U \subset X \iff g^{-1}(U) \subset Y$ holds due to surjectivity and continuity(?). So $g$ is indeed a quotient map.

Now to show that $f$ is an embedding we need to show that it's homeomoprhic onto it's image. By assumption it's continuous and since $g \circ f$ is injective $f$ is also injective. Therefore it satisfies to show that $f$ is open or closed map. This is where I ran in to problems. What properties can I use here to determine if $f$ is open or closed?

Comment: *Only* continuity is needed for $U$ open then $g^{-1}[U]$ open, of course. Surjectivity is only needed (in most texts) for being a quotient map.

Comment: You don't need to show the homeomorphism part, it follows from main theory: an embedding is just an injective function where the domain has the induced (or initial) topology, dual to a quotient being a surjective map where the codomain has the coinduced (or final) topology.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $g \circ f$ bijective implies $g \circ f$ surjective implies $g$ surjective.

Also: $g \circ f$ bijective implies $g \circ f$ injective implies $f$ injective.

That is just set theory. But we know even more: $g \circ f$ is the identity, not just a bijection.

To see that $g$ is quotient we need to show that **if** $g^{-1}[U]$ is open in $Y$ (so $U \subseteq X$) then $U$ is open (the other implication is given by continuity of $g$).

And $U = (1_X)^{-1}[U] = (g \circ f)^{-1}[U] = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]]$ is open as the inverse image (under the continuous $f$) of the assumedly open $g^{-1}[U]$. So QED.

The embedding fact is dual and can be shown similarly: An embedding is just an injective function where the domain has the induced (or initial) topology (wrt the codomain), dual to a quotient being a surjective map where the codomain has the coinduced (or final) topology (wrt the domain topology).

Comment: I cannot find this definition for a map to be an embedding. What I have is that $f$ is an embedding if $f$ is continuous injective and if $f^{-1} : f(X) \to X$ is continuous.

Comment: @Christie Well, that's trivial here: $g$ is the continuous inverse for $f: X \to f[X]$ so it's clear that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. It's also trivially dual to the other statement so take your pick.

Comment: @Christie: See if you agree... an embedding is an homemorphism to its image, where the image has the induced topology. The initial topology is composed of sets $f^{-1}(A)$, where $A \subset Y$ is open. But this is the same as $f^{-1}(A \cap f(X))$. And since $f$ with its co-domain restricted to $f(X)$ is a bijection, the initial topology is such that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $f(X)$, because the open sets in $f(X)$ are just those $A \cap f(X)$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas the **domain** has the induced topology wrt the codomain. An embedding is an injective induced map. Induced topologies are defined on the domain, coinduced ones on the codomain..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: My statement probably over complicated... sorry! I was trying to show that for an injection, "being a homeomorphism to its image" is the same as "having the induced topology with respect to the codomain". I hope I get this power to digest in a few words, as you do! :-)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Sorry again... I was using "induced" to mean "induced as a subspace": $f(X) \subset Y$. A very bad habit, since there are many ways to "induce" a topology. My bad again! :-)

Comment: @AndréCaldas The openness of $f$ is indeed clear from $f[f^{-1}[U \cap f[X] ]] = U \cap f[X]$ for (injective) $f$.. and the fact that this is the general form for an open set in $X$, when $f$ induces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130611/discussion-between-andre-caldas-and-henno-brandsma).

Comment: That $f$ is an embedding follows from the fact that $g \mid_{f(X)} : f(X) \to Y$ is inverse to $f: X \to f(X)$.